# tsconfig, outFile and angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

Having followed the instructions for the 5 minute quickstart at https://angular.io/guide/quickstart I thought I would try adding the following to tsconfig:

```
,outFile = "app/combinedApp.js"
```

and amend the index.html thus:

```
System.import('app/combinedApp')
```

However this singularly fails and I am left with the default text 'Loading'. There are no errors displayed on the console. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you followed tutorial: used `"module": "system"` in tsconfig.json and saved your bootstap in `app/main.ts`, you should do the following:

- Load your bundle with a script tag `<script src="app/combinedApp.js"></script>`,
- Instead of `System.import('app/combinedApp')` use:

  ```
  System.import('app/main')
  ```

where `app/main` is registered name of the module (you can find it in your bundle file).

Comment: I wonder if it's not rather: `System.import('app/main');`, @Sasxa... ;-) since the `app/main.ts` will correspond a `app/main module` in the JS output file.

Comment: I tested and I have this in the file: `System.register("app/main", ['angular2/platform/browser', "app/app.component", 'angular2/http'], function(exports_6, context_6) { ...`

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Updated the answer... Does example still work with `System.config.package` option set?

Comment: Great, @Saxsa! I think that you don't need `System.config.package`. It's the same when including the `angular2.dev.js` file for example... You don't need anything in the SystemJS configuration :-) The `package` block is to link packages with files.

Comment: Yup, if you still have it it will load files from network, not from memory. But if you have it when you compile it might change output module names (that's why I wrote just `main` the first time)...

Comment: But when you compile with tsc, System.config.package doesn't enter into account, no? It's only when you execute the application in the brower... No?

Comment: Yea, I think you're right. Tho' not 100% sure - imports are bit confusing (not in this example, but some larger apps where I tried `outfile`) as modules are usually registered without `app/` or `core/` prefix. I'll have to look into this at some point (;

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated.

My key takeaways if I wish to use outFile are:

1. add: <script src="app/combinedApp.js"></script> in index.html

2. amend: System.import('app/combinedApp') to System.import('main')

Comment: @a2dude Yup, that should solve your issue. And welcome to SO!

Comment: I *think* the reason that the script must be "manually" included via <script> tag has something to do with https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript#options : outFile: "Only works when no module system is used"  I can see the script being loaded via XHR, but nothing happens.